# System.QueryException: Implementation restriction: ContentDocumentLink?

Tags: query, exception, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink, queryexception

I have been following [this](https://salesforcescool.blogspot.com/2019/03/file-upload-lightning-component-using.html) to create a lightning component for lighting:file upload. As you can see there's comments on how to avoid the System.QueryException yet I still am getting it?

picture of logs-
[image]

controller code-

```
public class LightningFileUploadCtrl {

//retrieves all uploaded files associated with the record 
@AuraEnabled  
public static List<ContentDocument> getFiles(String recordId) { 
    
    Set<Id> recordIds = new Set<Id>{recordId};
    Set<Id> documentIds = new Set<Id>(); 
    
    List<ContentDocumentLink> cdlList = [SELECT Id, LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId IN:recordIds];                        
            
    for(ContentDocumentLink cdl :cdlList) {  
        documentIds.add(cdl.ContentDocumentId);  
    }    
    return [SELECT Id, Title, FileType FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id IN :documentIds];        
 } 
}
```

cmp where I call it-

```
<c:LightningFileUpload label="Upload Document(s)?" 
                                       recordId= "{!v.recordId}"
                                       />
```

Let me know if you need to see the LightningFileUpload components code as well.
Any ideas why this exception is occurring anyway?

Thanks!

edit:

added a debug statement and showing that recordId is returning as null, which is causing the error. now trying to figure out why its returning null...

Comment: Seems like the `recordId` parameter is null which causes the query filter not to work, add some debug log to cross check

Comment: Can you please also check if "force:hasRecordId" is there in the component markup and recordId is passed to the apex method.

Comment: @maniaccoder yup, both components have "force:hasRecordId". check my edit, could this be the reason?

Comment: yes the reason could be defining the type as "Id" instead of "String". please change it to "String" and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your WHERE clause for ContentDocumentLink as following
`WHERE LinkedEntityId = :recordIds`
instead of
`WHERE LinkedEntityId IN:recordIds`

Also, check if your recordId is not blank.

Comment: how do i check if the recordId is not blank?

Comment: you have to debug, when you call auraenabled apex method fro m lightning & add a system debug with recordId to the apex method.

Comment: yup, from debugging its returning as null. no idea as to why it would

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you create `Set` as you can just write.

`List<ContentDocumentLink> cdlList = [SELECT Id, LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = :recordId];`

But to answer your question, some Objects require explicit specification of Ids, so you need to specify them, you can do it via dynamic SOQL.

```
List<ContentDocumentLink> cdlList = Database.query('SELECT Id, LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId IN (\'' + String.join(recordIds, '\', \'') + '\')');
```

Comment: when I try this I get the following error: "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void join(Set<Id>, String) from the type String"

Comment: Then you're copying code incorrectly...

Comment: If you're only passing recordId, then use my first query!

Comment: i use your first query, but from debugging i see that recordId isn't being passed. it returns as null